# EDA, Descriptive statistics, Visual Analytics

Tags: terminology, exploratory-data-analysis

Is there any difference between EDA, Descriptive Statistics, and Visual Analytics?

Answer (score 2):

EDA (Exploratory Data Analysis) typically involves fitting models to see whether "anything is there". Descriptive Statistics just describes data. So there is a difference. One will usually first perform Descriptive Statistics, then either EDA or standard hypothesis tests if we already have hypotheses.

I am not familiar with the term "Visual Analytics", but it sounds like something that could involve only Descriptive Statistics (e.g., plotting scatterplots between pairs of data), or already include EDA elements (e.g., fitting models and overlaying best fit lines over the scatterplots).

Comment: Given that the seminal book on EDA (Tukey, 1977) doesn't ever mention or use something one might construe as a "model," I doubt your characterization of EDA is a commonly accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Exploratory Data Analysis(EDA) is used to analyze the data

1. To understand the data characteristics(Descriptive Statistics) and also
2. to observe any patterns shown by the data( Visual Representations/ Plots like Histogram, Scatter plot , line plot, etc.,)
3. It also serves as a pathway to derive insights and recommendations which is Inferential Statistics

When you have a business question, sometimes EDA can provide you the answer. In other cases, you will have to move further than EDA and perform Hypothesis testing or statistical modelling to figure out the answer.

To answer your question, EDA encompasses Descriptive Statistics and Visualizations.